# Is there any way I could share processing resources of two laptops?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have two laptops which is not enough powerful for my tasks. I wonder if there is any way I could link them and i have the total processing resources of these two laptops.

Comment: It depends on the task - they have to support multiprocessing. Can you give us more details on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My both lap-tops are dual-core Intel CPU and ddr2 RAM Which work on Windows 7 64bit . and because I'm programmer I'm trying to run VS.net 2010 and SQL Server2008 R2

Comment: You can run SQL Server on one and VS.net on the other, but you can't share more than that. Neither of those programs are cluster tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might be looking for is clustered computing.

> A cluster is a group of computers bound together into a common
>   resource pool. A given task can be executed on all computers or on any
>   specific computer in the cluster.

This way you can link your laptops together.

---

> What you require for a cluster?
>
> - At least **two computers** with Windows XP, Windows NT, SP6 or Windows 2000 **networked with some sort of LAN equipment** (hub, switch etc.).
> - Ensure during the Windows set up phase that TCP/IP, and NETBUI are installed, and that the network is started with all the network cards
>     detected and the correct drivers installed.

A complete guide for making a basic cluster can be found here | [Building Your Own Super  Computer](http://www.webstreet.com/super_computer.htm)

Comment: Your link is now broken